# Table Row Color Change upon change in column, not every other row

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT, how can I alternate (2 colors) the row colors in the table every time the value in the `id` element changes. Alternating every other row is simple.  Unfortunately when `for-each` expires, the variable goes out of scope.

Here is my xml:

```
<guests>
  <guest>
    <name>bob</name>
    <id>1</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>tom</name>
    <id>2</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>peter</name>
    <id>2</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>jim</name>
    <id>4</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>jake</name>
    <id>3</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>dave</name>
    <id>3</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>steve</name>
    <id>5</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>joe</name>
    <id>5</id>
  </guest>
  <guest>
    <name>............</name>
    <id>...........</id>
  </guest>
</guests>
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the XSLT you have now, and the output you're getting with it

Comment: This question is difficult to understand, because no wanted output is provided. Please, *edit* the question and provide this missing and important information.

Comment: I apologize.  First of all, the output was a simple HTML table.

Comment: The question is answered.  I'm having trouble answering my own question.   Thank You for your help

Answer (score 0):

XSLT does not have rows or columns or colors. I guess you meant to say you are generating an HTML table from this XML, and want to control the row colors? Please provide what you have done so far and why it doesn't work, and perhaps then someone would take a look at it. If you need a hint, you could consider adding a `class='changed-id'` attribute to the `tr` element whenever the id changes, which you could check by something like `@id != preceding:name/@id`. Then in your CSS you can do `.changed-id { color: pink; }`.

Comment: tora-thank you for the quick response.  A.  YES.  You are Correct.  The response is a simple HTML table from the XML.  B. I'm not even touching CSS here...I know I should... C.  I address "id" values all I want (preceding/folowing), but I don't know the row "colors" given another row/node-I need to know that in order to 'ALTERNATE'.  

clues???

Comment: The question has been answered.  I'm having trouble answering my own question.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think grouping is a good way to address this, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kGuest" match="guest" use="id"/>

    <xsl:template match="guests">
      <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
           select="guest[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kGuest', id)[1])]"
           mode="splitGroups" />
      </div>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="guest" mode="splitGroups">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kGuest', id)">
      <xsl:with-param name="class" 
                      select="concat('row-type', (position() - 1) mod 2 + 1)" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="guest">
    <xsl:param name="class" />
    <div class="{$class}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ' - ', name)" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample, this produces:

```
<div>
  <div class="row-type1">1 - bob</div>
  <div class="row-type2">2 - tom</div>
  <div class="row-type2">2 - peter</div>
  <div class="row-type1">4 - jim</div>
  <div class="row-type2">3 - jake</div>
  <div class="row-type2">3 - dave</div>
  <div class="row-type1">5 - steve</div>
  <div class="row-type1">5 - joe</div>
  <div class="row-type2">........... - ............</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `class` switches between `type1` and `type2` when the id changes to a new value.

Comment: The question is answered.  I'm having trouble answering my own question.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2013876 I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Did the answer I provided above answer your question or not?